# When to use Du and Le

Tags: articles

I was practicing at duolingo and I was required to translate the following sentece

> Nous mangeons le chocolat

It struck me. Shouldn't it be ?

> Nous mangeons du chocolat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that *Nous mangeons du chocolat* is often what you want to say - for "We are eating chocolate*.

But *Nous mangeons le chocolat* can be used at least in these two cases I can think about:

- *le chocolat* refers to one of these chocolates in a box. There are 20 chocolates in the box and we are eating one (OK it's strange if many people are eating one chocolate (not one each, one for all)) ;
- *le chocolat* refers to a precised piece of chocolate, the one you are talking about, the bar of chocolate you just bought, the leftovers of Easter eggs in a bowl, anything you could describe as *the chocolate* - *Did you really eat all the chocolate?!*.